# How to manage android app data in both server and local server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use firebase as my database.

I want to store data in server. After user first time read those data. I want to save only that new data in local server. So my users can use my application without internet connection.

When my users use application without internet connection. I want to save that data in local server and when the user connect to the internet I want to save them in server.

Comment: [Firebase Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will work for you.

Put this line in Your Application class onCreate() method

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

It will sync data to firebase after network connection available and for local database use SQLite database to save data locally.